# How to get part of the column value in sybase where this column situated in a query which is inside other query?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have a column named Cons in a table named Conses as `Order::Resource(PPP32#BB300320LQ00J#AAAR05504)`
I have second table which depends on first table.
i wants to get all data from the seconds table and i did it manually as below and result is ok

```
select * from so_db..item   where  id =('PPP32' )
                            and    sub_id =('BB300320LQ00J')
                            and    tem_id =('AAAR05504');
```

but i want to replace inside the parentheses with an other query which must get one part of  the column mentioned above as follow:

id = first part of column before '#' character

sun_id = middle part of column between '#' character

tem_id = last part of column

```
select * from so_db..item   where  id =( select Cons from er_db..Conses where UsedBy_ = 'mmmf8c713f490f8133c00e16ffdea136add')
                            and    sub_id =(select Cons from er_db..Conses where UsedBy_ = 'mmmf8c713f490f8133c00e16ffdea136add')
                            and    tem_id =(select Cons from er_db..Conses where UsedBy_ = 'mmmf8c713f490f8133c00e16ffdea136add');
```

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to do string manipulation.

Use [substring](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks215.htm), [charindex](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks120.htm), [char_length](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks119.htm), [right](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks194.htm) and [left](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks164.htm) functions :)

---

```
declare @string varchar(50)
select @string = 'Order::Resource(PPP32#BB300320LQ00J#AAAR05504)'
declare @start int, @end int, @secondstring varchar(100)

select @start = charindex('#',@string)
select @secondstring = substring(@string, @start+1, len(@string))

select @end = charindex('#',@secondstring)

select substring(@string,charindex('(', @string)+1, @start-1-charindex('(', @string)),
       substring(@string,@start+1,@end-1), 
       substring(@string, @start+@end+1, len(@string)-(@start+@end+1))
```

Comment: could you please correct the result of last sub-string which contains ')'. i'm gonna accept your solution. thanks a lot

Comment: @itro I've already did it. I did it also here when I corrected the other one.