# how extract sub-string from string in sybase?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

With a query i get this string `"Order::Resource(PPP32#BB300320LQ00J#AAAR05504)"`.
I want to extract string before, between and after # character as following:

id = PPP32

sub_id = BB300320LQ00J

sup_id =AAAR05504

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get part of the column value in sybase where this column situated in a query which is inside other query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173470/how-to-get-part-of-the-column-value-in-sybase-where-this-column-situated-in-a-qu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct solution:

```
declare @string varchar(50)
select @string = 'Order::Resource(PPP32#BB300320LQ00J#AAAR05504)'
declare @start int, @end int, @secondstring varchar(100)

select @start = charindex('#',@string)
select @secondstring = substring(@string, @start+1, len(@string))

select @end = charindex('#',@secondstring)

select substring(@string,charindex('(', @string)+1, @start-1-charindex('(', @string)),
       substring(@string,@start+1,@end-1), 
       substring(@string, @start+@end+1, len(@string)-(@start+@end+1))
```

Comment: CHARINDEX - [FairCom][ODBC FairCom Driver 9.5.59340(Build-120902)][ctreeSQL] -20183 Function not found

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @start int, @end int, @secondstring varchar(100)

select @start = charindex('#',@string)
select @secondstring = substring(@string, @start+1, len(@string))

select @end = charindex('#',@secondstring)

select substring(@string,1, @start-1),
       substring(@string,@start+1,@end-1), 
       substring(@string, @start+@end+1, len(@string)-@end)
```

Comment: `charindex` function only takes 2 arguments in sybase.